# Multiple collapsible div not working

Tags: jquery

Hello everyone actually I am facing a problem I have multiple plus and minus div which on click should display content.But when I am clicking on one plus icon the other icon performs the action of show and hide content.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="expandContent1"><a><h1><img id="arrow1" src="plus.png">One</h1>   </a>

</div>
<div class="showMe1" style="display:none">This content was hidden, but now shows up</div>

<script>
var div_show = $('.showMe1'),
arrow = $('#arrow1');
 $('.expandContent1').click(function () {
div_show.slideToggle('slow', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        arrow.prop('src', 'minus.png');
    } else {
        arrow.prop('src', 'plus.png');
    }
   });
 });
 </script>
  </div>
   <div class="expandContent2"><a><h1><img id="arrow2" src="plus.png">Two</h1></a>

</div>
<div class="showMe2" style="display:none">This content was hidden, but now shows up</div>

<script>
var div_show = $('.showMe2'),
arrow = $('#arrow2');
$('.expandContent2').click(function () {
div_show.slideToggle('slow', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        arrow.prop('src', 'minus.png');
    } else {
        arrow.prop('src', 'plus.png');
    }
  });
  });
</script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="expandContent">
    <a><h1><img src="plus.png">One</h1></a>
</div>
<div class="showMe" style="display:none">
    This content was hidden, but now shows up
</div>
<div class="expandContent">
    <a><h1><img src="plus.png">Two</h1></a>
</div>
<div class="showMe" style="display:none">
    This content was hidden, but now shows up
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('img')
    .on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this), $content = $this.closest('div').next('div.showMe');
        $('div.showMe')
            .not($content[0])
            .slideUp('slow', function () {
                $('img')
                    .not($this[0])
                    .prop('src', 'minus.png');
        });
        $content
            .slideToggle('slow', function () {
                if($content.is(':visible')) {
                    $this
                        .prop('src', 'plus.png');
                } else {
                    $this
                        .prop('src', 'minus.png');
                }
        });
    });
```

Here is the [`FIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/brbxzbnv/3/).

Comment: Thank you for that :) But what should I do if i have to hide others contents and only display one div at a time when we click on plus.For eg:If I click on + One and then + Two the content of one remains there it does not hide.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to create the click function for each div block.
This can be easily handled by jquery

UPADTED code - This handle proper toggling of images (plus & minus) also it will collapse other divs except the one that is clicked

```
 $("div[class*='expandContent']").click(function () {
    $("div[class*='expandContent']").not(this).next('div').hide();
    $('img',$("div[class*='expandContent']").not(this)).prop('src', 'http://www.scheiblecker.com/wp-content/themes/crius-child/images/icon_plus.png');
    $maindiv = $(this);
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle('slow', function () {
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
            $('img',$maindiv).prop('src', 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/drf/PNG/minus%20white.png');
        } else {
            $('img',$maindiv).prop('src', 'http://www.scheiblecker.com/wp-content/themes/crius-child/images/icon_plus.png');
        }
    });
});
```

The selector "div[class*='expandContent']" will apply the click function on all div`s that have a class starting with`expandContent`

Check out the UPDATED Demo Here -http://jsfiddle.net/68uvf0c3/2/

Comment: @user1933852 - I have updated the demo fiddle & also the answer. Please check , if you feel this is helpful , please mark it as the answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code instead of your js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[class^="expandContent"]').on('click',function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        alert($this.index());  $('div[class^="expandContent"]').next('div[class^="showMe"]').not($this.next('div[class^="showMe"]')).slideUp();
        $('div[class^="expandContent"]').next('div[class^="showMe"]').not($this.next('div[class^="showMe"]')).find('img[id^="arrow"]').attr('src','minus.png');
        $this.next('div[class^="showMe"]').slideToggle(1000, function(){
            var changeSrc = (($this.find('img[id^="arrow"]').attr('src')) == 'plus.png') ? 'minus.png' : 'plus.png';
            $this.find('img[id^="arrow"]').attr('src',changeSrc);
        });

    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/sznkuo70/2/)

your full code will be

```
<div class="expandContent1"><a><h1><img id="arrow1" src="plus.png">One</h1></a></div>

<div class="showMe1" style="display:none">This content was hidden, but now shows up</div>

<div class="expandContent2"><a><h1><img id="arrow2" src="plus.png">Two</h1></a></div>

<div class="showMe2" style="display:none">This content was hidden, but now shows up</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[class^="expandContent"]').on('click',function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        alert($this.index());  $('div[class^="expandContent"]').next('div[class^="showMe"]').not($this.next('div[class^="showMe"]')).slideUp();
        $('div[class^="expandContent"]').next('div[class^="showMe"]').not($this.next('div[class^="showMe"]')).find('img[id^="arrow"]').attr('src','minus.png');
        $this.next('div[class^="showMe"]').slideToggle(1000, function(){
            var changeSrc = (($this.find('img[id^="arrow"]').attr('src')) == 'plus.png') ? 'minus.png' : 'plus.png';
            $this.find('img[id^="arrow"]').attr('src',changeSrc);
        });

    });
});
</script>
```